# Email notification when 'updated_at' become 2 hours before current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to make an email notification if SomeModel has not been updated for 2 hours.
What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

After a model has been saved, queue up a background job to run 2 hours from that time to send the email. When a new job is enqueued, remove any still-unrun jobs that are still on the queue.

[`resque-scheduler`](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) providers a pretty simple way of doing this, assuming you have redis up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find the solution that @x1a4 proposes to be somewhat overkill.  Given the relatively large window of 2 hours, I would just run a job periodically (say, once every 10-15 minutes), then search all Models for updated_at <= 2.hours.ago and send out the emails.

As for scheduling that job to run every 15 minutes, there are several options. You may use [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler), if you are using Resque.  You may also use the standard system cron, but will incur some fairly substantial overhead starting Rails each time the job runs.  I also [have written a distributed scheduler gem](https://github.com/flippa/allora) (i.e. cron that can run on multiple machines, but act like it's only running on one), which uses Redis under the hood.